# How to remove a tester's account from Google Play Console?

Tags: android, account, google-play-console, beta-testing

In the [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish), how can I remove a tester's account from open, closed or internal test tracks?

- I removed the email address from the tester list
- I clicked on the "Remove testers" button

It had no effect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way.

Note that this will not remove the version currently installed on their device nor downgrade to the production version. However they won't be eligible for future versions in those testing tracks and will receive the production version as soon as it has a higher versionCode as what they have currently installed.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Sign in Play Console > Choose your app > Click Release Overview (Left pane) > Select Internal testing > Select the internal app version

**2.** Under the "Testers" tab, scroll to the bottom and you can see this "Copy Link". Tap on the "Copy link" button and send this to your internal testers. (see picture below)
[image]

**3.** Once they tap on **LEAVE THE PROGRAM**, they will have opted-out of your internal testing list and redirect to the next page. (see picture below)

[image]

**4.** On next page, you can find "Install the public version on Google play". **(Note: It may take a few hours before you can download the public version)**. (see picture below)

[image]

**5.** If you want to download public version of the app immediately, you have to delete the data and cache of the Google Play Store app and then you can install public version of the app immediately.